# How to optimize docker build for react-application with lot of node modules

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, jenkins, docker-build

I am using docker to build and deploy the react-application. It takes a lot of time to build the docker almost 20-25 mins.

I tried to find out why it is taking so much time and find out that from step 9 to step 10. It is removing intermediate container and its taking 10 mins to do that.

```
05:39:57 | Step 9/18 : RUN cd /app/web && yarn install
    05:43:38 | Done in 219.92s.
    05:49:36 | Removing intermediate container 9ffd2edc0daa **TOOK almost 10 minutes to remove intermediate container**
05:49:36 | Step 10/18 : COPY . ./
```

Any idea/suggestion how to optimize this so it won't take this much time.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add the complete Dockerfile?

Comment: Generally the answer would be do use caching from an older image, copy only package*.json and install, then copy source code, that way it won't reinstall everytime source code changes, but nothing within the package changes